# Why is the output 255 instead of infinity?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char c = 0;
    int count=0;
    for (;++c;)
        count++;
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this program printing 255 instead of going to infinity?

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but how long would it take to count to infinity?

Comment: @AndrewHenle An eternity.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The C standard does not specify performance, and compilers are permitted to optimize, so infinity can be reached in finite time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But that's not *counting* to infinity.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Sure it is, counting to infinity by infinity instead of by ones. Same observable behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, strictly speaking you [can't count with infinite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting#Counting_in_mathematics): "Infinite sets cannot be counted in the usual sense; for one thing, the mathematical theorems which underlie this usual sense for finite sets are false for infinite sets."  :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That is talking about counting the members of sets (infinite or otherwise), not counting with/by infinity.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, no integer is ever going to reach infinity. Integers have a fixed range of values. You could probably have expected your `int count` to get to a value like 2,147,483,647 (32-bit) or 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (64-bit).

The reason it didn't, is that that's not what your program does. Your program increments `count` only while `++c` as a boolean condition evaluates truthfully. That stops happening once `c` itself runs out of values.

- If `char` is signed in your environment, that happens at `127`; then, having reached the maximum possible value for such a type, you run into complicated and implementation-defined rules, in your case apparently wrapping around back to `-128` then proceeding to `0`. That's 255 steps.
- If it's unsigned, it goes from `0` to `255` then wraps back to `0` in a well-defined manner. That's still 255 steps.

The following subtly altered `for` loop moves the increment of `c` from the *condition* part into the *post-iteration step* part, so it no longer determines how long the loop runs for:

```
for (;;++c)
 count++;
```

However, now your whole program has undefined behaviour because it describes a thread that never terminates or performs I/O.

Comment: There is no signed overflow in this program. For the signed `char` case: `++c` is defined as equivalent to `c += 1`. `c += 1` is defined as equivalent to `c = c + 1` except that the lvalue `c` is evaluated only once. In `c + 1`, `c` is promoted to `int`, and 127 + 1 does not overflow `int`. Then 128 is converted to `char`. This is implementation-defined, per C 6.3.1.3 3.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair. I have my C++ hat on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, even though I don't fully understand what it means.

Comment: @LjupcheToshev Which book are you using?

Comment: If you are going to judge [axiac’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662703/298225) as incomplete, then this one is too. The behavior reported in the problem can occur in a C implementation with a signed nine-bit `char` in which the conversion of an out-of-range value to `char` is defined to produce zero. Thus, the program counts 1 to 255, increments to 256, produces zero in the conversion, and exits the loop.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Why I do not write my own answer? Because sometimes I take the time to reflect, maybe when I think there are subtleties or complications that ought to be thought through. Other times, I answer quickly, maybe when I think a valuable concept can be conveyed without too much imprecision. It depends on circumstances, and, when a number of people have jumped on a question, it can be hard to get the mud to settle and get a clear answer through. It is a shame you regard factual statements as complaints. These are information that can be used to improve answers.

Comment: Nonetheless, whether or not another person writes an answer has no bearing on the good or bad points of others. It is no defense of this answer to complain that somebody else has not yet written one.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `char` type can only hold 0 - 255 (or -128 - 127, that doesn't matter in this case). After 255 it will overflow and go back to `0`. `0` evaluates to `false` and thus the for loop is broken.

Comment: The `char` type does not need to be unsigned for this output to occur.

Comment: if it was int instead of char would it be signed and go to infinitive or to a limit?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah you're right, misread. Thanks, edited.

Comment: @LjupcheToshev You cannot represent infinity with integers, at least in C.

Comment: This answer assumes `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'll sign your key

Answer (score 0):

The data in computers is stored on a certain amount of memory. In this case, `c` (of type `char`) is stored on one byte, consequently it may have only 256 distinct values. If you insist on incrementing its value it wraps and when it reaches `0` again the `for` loop completes.

Given that it starts with `0` and it is incremented before checking its value, the `for` loop runs only 255 times; on the 256<sup>th</sup> increment of `c` its value becomes `0` again.

Comment: This answer assumes `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Not quite. Even if `char` is signed, it is true it may have only 256 distinct values (if it is eight-bits, and fewer if it is not two’s complement), and that it becomes zero again on the 256th increment, unless the implementation defines a trap for converting out-of-range values to `char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You said yourself, with a standard citation, that the result in such a case is implementation-defined. Until and unless this answer addresses that, it can only truthfully be talking about the unsigned case.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings the OP says "I'm new with coding". Using terms like _"implementation defined"_ and _"undefined behaviour"_ does not make the answer more clear for beginners, on the contrary.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Each sentence in this answer is true inside the OP’s C implementation. The answer is correct, albeit “starts over” is vague.

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

The program prints “255” because the loop iterates through 255 values before `c` becomes zero again, triggering the condition to end the loop.

### Medium Answer

C permits `char` to be signed or unsigned. If it is unsigned, `char` is eight bits in your C implementation, and the program increments it from 1 to 255. The next increment resets it to zero, because unsigned arithmetic and conversions are defined to wrap, and the loop stops.

If `char` is signed, the behavior of `++c` when the value would be out of range of `char` is implementation-defined (due to a chain of rules in the definition of `++`). Most likely your implementation uses an eight-bit char with values from −128 to 127, and, when the value would go to 128, it is wrapped to −128. Thus, 255 values are counted (127 from 1 to 127 and 128 from −128 to −1) before `c` becomes zero again and the loop stops because its test expression, `++c`, evaluates to zero.

A theoretical possibility under the C standard that does not occur in practice is that your implementation uses a nine-bit char with values from −256 or −255 to 255 and, when the value would go to 256, it is reset to zero.

### Long Answer

`++c` is a surprising complicated operation:

- C 2018 6.5.3.1 2 defines it to be equivalent to `c += 1`.
- C 2018 6.5.16.2 3 defines `c += 1` to be equivalent to `c = c + 1`, except that the lvalue for `c` is evaluated only once.
- C 6.5.6 4 tells us that the *usual arithmetic conversions* are performed on the operands of `+`.
- The usual arithmetic conversions involve several clauses in 6.3 that result in `int` arithmetic being used. Since `int` represents values up to at least 32,767, no out-of-range issues occur in this addition.
- Finally, C 6.5.16.1 2 tells us the result of the addition is converted to `char`. This is where the interesting things happen with out-of-range values.

C 2018 6.3.1.3 tells us what happens with conversions to `char`. There are only three ways that the loop could iterate through 255 values and then produce zero in `c`:

- `char` is unsigned and eight bits, so it represents values from 0 to 255. When the addition produces 256, 6.3.1.3 2 tells us the conversion wraps modulo 256, producing zero.
- `char` is unsigned, eight bits, and two’s complement, so it represents values from −128 to +127. When the addition produces 128, 6.3.1.3 3 tells us the result is implementation-defined. Your implementation produces −128. After that, the increments proceed from −128 to −1 and to zero, and then the loop stops.
- `char` is unsigned, and no bits, so it represents values from either −256 or −255 to +255. When the addition produces 256, your implementation produces zero. Then the loop stops. (This does not occur in normal practice; it is only a theoretical possibility under the C standard.)

We know `char` is either eight or nine bits because that is the only way the count could be 255. If it were seven bits (which the C standard does not permit anyway), there is no way to count 255 distinct values. If it were ten bits or more, the count would go up to at least 511 before the implementation-defined conversion could reset `c`.